# Laravel Mix: Custom Less Loader processed twice

Tags: javascript, webpack, less, antd, laravel-mix

I'm trying to add `less-loader` to my Laravel Mix configuration because some of my imported modules need it.

I've tried the following way, but when starting the dev environment, it looks like my less file is processed twice:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/es/style/index.less (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--12-2!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-2!./node_modules/antd/es/style/index.less)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> var content = require("!!../../../css-loader/index.js!../../../less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-2!./index.less");
>
> Unrecognised input

**Does anybody know where the issue is or what I'm doing wrong?**

```
mix.reactTypeScript('resources/js/app.tsx', 'public/js')
  .less('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
  .copyDirectory('resources/img', 'public/img')
  .webpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          loader: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   ]}
 })
 .version();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Assuming the `javascriptEnabled` option is required, you can put it in the mix less function

```
.less('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', {
   lessOptions: { javascriptEnabled: true }
})
```

For other less files, It seems that we need to modify existing less rules

```
Mix.listen("configReadyForUser", function (config) {
    var ruleIndex = config.module.rules.findIndex(function (rule) {
        return rule.test.toString() === /\.less$/.toString();
    });
    var loaderIndex = config.module.rules[ruleIndex].loaders.findIndex(function (loader) {
        return loader === 'less-loader';
    });
    config.module.rules[ruleIndex].loaders[loaderIndex] = {
        loader: 'less-loader',
        options: {
            lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: lessOptions: { javascriptEnabled: true } save me, thank u